# How to center the button before drawing it?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to set position of button in the center of my GUI window:

```
capture_button = Button(self, text="Capture", command=self.client_exit)
capture_button.place(x=100, y=100)
```

But there is a problem - button's centre is not at (100,100) but its left top corner is at (100,100) so there is no symmetry. So I decided to do something like that:

```
capture_button.place(x=100+buttonsize.x/2, y=100 - buttonsize.y/2)
```

I know that I can use

```
capture_button.winfo_width
```

but that works after first draw - how can I do this before drawing, just in ctor of python class? Or there are other ways like `setOrigin(centre)` and then setting position?

Comment: You can specify the width and height of a button when you create it. Here's some [`Button` documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html). If you specify these values, then you should be able to figure out where to place it so it's centered.

Comment: [This](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) information on using the `place` geometry manager, says it's usually better to use the `pack` or `grid` mangers instead. That said, I think you could use something like `capture_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)` to center it (as shown in the first example of its usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your real goal is simply to center the button using `place`, you can use relative coordinates instead of relying on computing the width of the button.

```
capture_button.place(anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)
```